# Pop to home screen

Tags: blackberry

In my app I fave some screens one after another, and I need to pop to home screen any time. Is there any way to find out is active screen is the first one? Or, may be, there is any function to pop to root screen without cycle of poping to previous ones?

---

**EDIT** In different words, I need my app to go to previous screen on click on blackberry "back" button (it do this without any additional code), and go to the screen, user first see when starts this application on click on "Home" button from my user interface

Comment: what you want to do actually ??? Do you want to exitting the application from any off your screen ??

Comment: no, I whant to go to screen, the user first see when starts the applicatin.

Comment: add a menu in all your screen `go to home screen` and just push the home screen in that menu's run method

Comment: is This usual for blackberry? what about memory? Can this to overflow screens's stack?

Comment: no not overflow you can pop the active screen and push the new screen so the previous screen will not be on stack

Comment: let me explane more clearly: Application can have <10 screens in stack. I need to go to the first of them, and then, more 10 can come. Are they really don't store in the memory? How can it be?

Comment: I guess, I must approve your answer, can you post it as an "answer"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This helps you any time and any where:

Write this method in startup class(**StartUp.java**):

```
public static void popupScreens()
{
    int screenCount = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getScreenCount();//Gives how many screens are active state in background;
    for (int i = 0; i < screenCount; i++) 
    {
        Screen screen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(screen);
    }
}
```

and call this method at any place with class name(EX: **StartUp.popupScreens**) in any where then it popup all the screens in the stack.

Comment: there was a little bug there: `popupScreens()` poped all screens, including the first one. we need to pop `screenCount - 1` screens

Answer (score 1):

First, you will need to organize your screens, application logic and clearly define what screens you want to be on the UI stack and those that don't. For those screens that don't need to be on UI stack, you can dismiss them automatically when another screen is pushed on top of it:

```
class SplashScreen extends FullScreen
{

protected void onObscured()
{
  close();
}
}
```

Comment: tnx for responce. I need my app to go to previous screen on click on blackberry "back" button (it do this without any additional code), and go to the screen, user first see when starts this application on click on "Home" button from my user interface. So,  If I'll do just like you sad, it will go to Home screen in any case. May be I can find out what case of returning back did choosed by user somehow, and "close();" all sceens only when "home" button was pressed?

Comment: Well, what you are asking is something very application specific. Does your application need 10 Screens, if so how is the navigation managed between those screens, which screens are transient etc - such questions are subjective to your application and are best addressed by the usability expert. Coming back to your question, you  don't have to override onObsured for the screen that will respond to your BACK screen. As I understand your question, you seem to be having an _extra_ screen in between the top and the one you want to show. This calls for re-design of the UI. Consult design expert!

Comment: Oh, if only I could do this...  You see, I'm not developing a new app: I'm porting old one from iPhone. Design vas focused for iPhone. So, I'm going crazy with blackberry's layout and navogation managemant. Coding like some kind of barbarian, puting empty objects with custom frame. just to make buttons and images be on right place...

Comment: @SentineL -:) I can empathize with you. Though we have come out of jungles, the wild animals are lurking in dark to pounce on you any moment. Fight must go on!

Answer (score 0):

Add menu to the Screen for having option `Gotohomescreen` some thing like this. Just pop the active screen from the display stack an push your home screen from the `menus's run()` method. For efficiently. If you want to go back in your application you can pop the active screen and it will go to that screen from where you have come.Let suppose you have added a `backButton` you can just override the fieldchanged method of the button and in fieldchanged method do something like this.

```
if(field == backbutton) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());             
        }
```

**using the memory here is your answer**

The screen at the top of the stack is the active screen that the BlackBerry device user sees. When a BlackBerry device application displays a screen, it pushes the screen to the top of the stack. When a BlackBerry device application closes a screen, it removes the screen off the top of the stack and displays the next screen on the stack, redrawing it as necessary. Each screen can appear only once in the display stack. The `BlackBerry JVM throws a runtime exception` if a Screen that the BlackBerry device application pushes to the stack already exists.
A BlackBerry device application must remove screens from the display stack when the BlackBerry device user finishes interacting with them so that the BlackBerry device application uses memory efficiently