# Clearing Screen stack and disable back button in Blackberry Application

Tags: java, blackberry, back-button

I have a requirement to restrict the user from pressing back button or disabling the back button in a screen. How should I get the Task done?

And Also on the same screen if user clicks the Ok button all the Screens from Home should get cleared and Home Screen should be displayed.

I got an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8385917/1649309) but it doesn't work. I am testing the app on Simulator 9550. Don't whether it is OS issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to modify the behaviour when the user presses ESC / back, you simply override the [keyChar() method](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Field.html#keyChar(char,%20int,%20int)) in your `Screen` subclass(es):

```
protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) {
  if (c == Characters.ESCAPE) {
     // do nothing if ESC was pressed
     return true;
  } else {
     // accept the default behaviour for other keys
     return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
  }
}
```

In order to pop (remove) all screens except the app's home screen [see this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15824485/119114) ... the one you linked to has a bug in it.